# How to avoid JQuery Pop Up window to cover the whole screen width?

Tags: jquery, popupwindow

I am trying to insert JQuery pop window using a plugin. Though, its working fine, but whenever the pop up window gets displayed, it covers the whole screen width. Height is fine but width is covering the whole screen. 
I tried to use the width attribute given in plugin documentation, but the same not working, while rest of the attribute working as expected.

Below is the sample code.

```
   function shw(){
        $.confirm({
            boxWidth: '30%',
            animation: 'Rotate', 
    title: 'Prompt!',
    content: '' +
    '<form action="" class="formName">' +
    '<div class="form-group">' +
    '<label>Enter something here</label>' +
    '<input type="text" placeholder="Your name" class="name form-control" required />' +
    '</div>' +
    '</form>',
    buttons: {
        formSubmit: {
            text: 'Submit',
            btnClass: 'btn-blue',
            action: function () {
                var name = this.$content.find('.name').val();
                if(!name){
                    $.alert('provide a valid name');
                    return false;
                }
                $.alert('Your name is ' + name);
            }
        },
        cancel: function () {
            //close
        },
    },
    onContentReady: function () {
        // bind to events
        var jc = this;
        this.$content.find('form').on('submit', function (e) {
            // if the user submits the form by pressing enter in the field.
            e.preventDefault();
            jc.$$formSubmit.trigger('click'); // reference the button and click it
        });
    }
});

        }
```

Here method shw() is called on a button click event.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code. See [MCVE].

Comment: Question edited and code added.

Comment: As per the plugin documentation, the attribute 'boxwidth' is used to set the size of the popup box. Here its not working. Do, it requires any browser changes or similar?

Comment: The docs say 'useBootstrap must be set to false to use this feature'  (`boxWidth`) - have you done that?

Comment: @peeebeee.. thankyou, its working. I set the bootstrap to false, its working now. Thanks again.

Comment: I've added this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs for the `jquery-confirm` plugin (https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/#custom-width-without-bootstrap), to set the `customWidth` option you also have to set `useBootstrap: false`.